# PowerShell command against multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I have the following script I want to run against multiple servers

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | #InstallDate  
    Format-Table –AutoSize |
    Out-File C:\Temp\InventoryTestScripts.txt
```

Currently this output is saved on the server it is ran from. I would like to run this command against 30 different servers and have the output from each server saved to one file. I would also need a way to indicate what result set came from what server in the file.

Comment: Take a look at `Invoke-Command`... I'll provide a full answer shortly.

Comment: Searching your title here on SO returns this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009970/how-to-run-a-command-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously-in-powershell. Should be a dupe. Likely there are others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[string[]]$servers = 'server1,server2,server3' -split ',' #put a list of servers into an array; you can get these however (typically read from a file; in this case splittling a comma separated string)
$credential = Get-Credential #this will prompt you to enter your account credentials
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate 
} | Format-Table PSComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```